# ASP.NET authenticating user with shared SSL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, ssl

Ok here is my situation. I am in the process of publishing my website (ASP.NET MVC3 site), and I have an admin section which will of course require authentication.

Now the hosting provider that I have chosen to go with provide a shared SSL folder, and from what I have read I will need a separate, "authenticating webapp", which will be published to the shared SSL folder.

My question is, what is the best, and safest way to perform this sort of authentication? Essentially this will be a cross-site authentication yes??

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

I believe the shared ssl folder will have name "www.mysite.com/sslfolder". This will be on the same domain as mysite, thus this will greatly simplify the solution.

The question is, on my mvc3 project, how do I know route www.mysite.com/sslfolder to my login controller?

Is this just a simple as adding the routing to the route table??

Comment: how the shared ssl folder looks compare with your url name ? eg you have www.yoursite.com and the shared ssl is sharesll.yoursite.com, or is www.sharessl.com ?

Comment: I believe it is "www.yoursite.com/sharedssl". Strange I thought it was "www.providername.com/mysite/sharedssl"...

Comment: If you keep your url name, then there is not big issue. as you say it will only a routing setup to your route table.

Comment: Ok thanks. But out of curiosity, if the shared ssl folder did indeed have a different domain, what would you recommend as the safest solution??